# provide a list of latitudes and longitudes to my google map to visualize them with markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In my project, I have a database containing a list of latitudes and longitudes, corresponding to several addresses, and I want to take them from this database and pass them to a javascript code that will show all these addresses in a map using markers. So far I got all the list from the database. and I was able to visualize one and only one address in the map by using it's latitude and longitude. So what I am struggeling with now is doing so for multiple addresses. Here is the code that I came up with so far:

```
      function initialize() {
          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0], locations[1]);
          var myOptions = {
              zoom: 4,
              center: myLatlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          }
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              map: map,
              title: "Fast marker"
          });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

locations is the list of my latitudes and longitudes, and it goes like this:

```
locations[0]: latitude 1  
locations[1]: longitude 1  
locations[2]: latitude 2  
locations[3]: longitude 2    etc..
```

Now I know there is supposed to be some kind of loop but I couldn't manage to do it.

Thanks in advance!

P.S: This is my first question so don't judge my accept rate! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to write a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop as follows:

```
function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0], locations[1]),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  for (var i = 0, ln = locations.length; i < ln; i += 2) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i], locations[i + 1]);
      map: map,
      title: "Fast marker"
    });
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);​
```

Comment: well I first though this is the solution, but it actually only gives me a marker for the last address. So it only takes locations[ln-1] as lat and locations[ln] as lng!

Comment: sorry this comment was intended for some other answer. It works thanks a lot ! your link gave me the answer.

Comment: hi, @StephenYoung , could you convert this into a google maps url? i would like to share it with people.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple `for` loop to [iterate through `locations`](http://jsfiddle.net/XD5tS/1/).   Increment two at a time:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

for (var i=0 ; i < locations.length-1 ; i+=2) {

    var lat = locations[i];
    var lng = locations[i+1];

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var myOptions = {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: "Fast marker"
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this code. Apparently "myLatlng" is not defined in your code!

Comment: opp sorry this is meant to be for the other answer! this is the comment that was meant to be for your answer: 
well I first though this is the solution, but it actually only gives me a marker for the last address. So it only takes locations[locations.length-1] as lat and locations[locations.lengt] as lng!

Comment: @zahidaoui I think I see the problem -- currently the map object is being recreated for each iteration, and adding the current marker, so that you only end up seeing the last marker.  Move the map initialization outside of the loop, as above.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. if anybody needs it in the future here is the code:

```
    function initialize() {
    console.log('hi');
  var myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0], locations[1]),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    for (var i = 0, ln = locations.length; i < ln; i += 2) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i], locations[i + 1]),
          map: map,
          title: "Fast marker"
      });
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of locations like following

```
var locations = [
    [33.890542, 150.274856],
    [36.923036, 152.259052],
    [38.028249, 154.157507]
];
```

then you can use following code

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][0], locations[0][1]);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    for(var i=0;i<locations.length;i++)
    {
        var latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: "marker : "+(i+1)
        });
    }     
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/nGrSR/1/).
You may need/like other Google map related [**answers here**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A741747%5Bjavascript%5D+google+maps).